# How to use custom sort function on column header click, angular 6 + ngx-easy-table library

Tags: sorting, html-table, angular6

**Angular version: 6**
**Table library: ngx-easy-table**
**Library reference links:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-easy-table?file=app%2Fcomponents%2Fserver-sort%2Fserver-sort.component.ts
https://github.com/ssuperczynski/ngx-easy-table/wiki

Using the above table library, I want to sort certain columns using my custom sort function on the click of that particular column header/title. There is an example of custom sort in the stackblitz link provided above which enables us to do that but by placing a separate button for each column.

Also, am using `<ng-template>` to render the table data as below:

```
<ngx-table [configuration]="configuration" [data]="upcomingBookingsList" [columns]="columns" (event)="eventEmitted($event)">
  <ng-template let-row>
    <td>
      <a class="list-id-styles" (click)="openBookingDetailsModal(row['id'])">{{row.id}}</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      {{row.webStatus}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{row.guestDOB }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{row.startDateNTime }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{row.updateDate }}
    </td>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-table>
```

It would be great to get some help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of this library. 
Solution is really simple. Please check link [here](https://stackblitz.com/github/ssuperczynski/ngx-easy-table?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fcustom-intable-sort%2Fcustom-intable-sort.component.ts) where this example is described.

You need to check in the `eventEmitted` method which header key has been clicked. Then call your custom sort method, in this case `sortByLastName`

```js
eventEmitted($event) {
  if ($event.event === 'onOrder') {
    if ($event.value.key === 'name') {
      this.sortByLastName($event.value.order === 'asc');
    }
}
```

```js
private sortByLastName(asc: boolean): void {
  this.data = [...this.data.sort((a, b) => {
    const nameA = a.name.toLowerCase().split(' ')[1];
    const nameB = b.name.toLowerCase().split(' ')[1];
    if (nameA < nameB) {
      return asc ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
      return asc ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
  })];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ssuperczynski, I was using version 5 of the library and hence didn't get to this solution. I upgraded it to version 6.0 and was able to make it work! :)